# mostrar spinner hasta que finalice una solicitud http javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spinner, requests

necesito ayuda.
Desde mi front angular 8 estoy enviando datos al backend hecho en spring en la cual ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado el cual se demora de 15 a 20 segundos en ejecutarse.
Pero mientras se ejecuta ese proceso programe que el spinner dure 20 segundos.
hay alguna manera de programar o configurar el spinner para que se muestre hasta que termine de ejecutarse el procedimiento automaticamente ya que en mi maquina se demora 15-20 segundos y en otras maquinas se demora mas.

***Component.ts***

```
     import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-exportacion',
          templateUrl: './exportacion.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./exportacion.component.scss'],
          providers: [NgxSpinnerService, MessageService]
        })
        
constructor(private restService: RestService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private toastr: 
            ToastrService { }
        
    //Función que ejecuta el procedimiento
          Ejecución(modelRespuesta: Respuesta){ 

    //cargo  y cierro el spinner manualmente
           this.spinner.show();
                setTimeout(() => { this.spinner.hide(); }, 20000,);
                this.restService.addData(modelRespuesta, "procesos/respuestas").subscribe(
                  res => {
                    console.log('exito proceso: ',modelRespuesta);
                    this.toastr.success("Proceso Ejecutado Exitosamente: ");
                   
                  },
                  err => {
                    this.error = err.error.mensaje;
                    this.toastr.error("Error al ejecutar el proceso almacenado: ", this.error);
                  }
                );
            }
```

***RestService.ts***

//Método Post

```
 addData(sistema, add: String) {
        return this.http.post(API_URL_FORM + add, sistema, http).pipe(
          map(
            (res: any) => {
              return res;
            },
            error => {
              console.log('error: ', error);
            }
          ));
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que yo te recomiendo es que una vez que muestres tu **spinner** en lugar de ocultarlo de esta manera:

```
setTimeout(() => { this.spinner.hide(); }, 20000,);
```

Lo ocultes cuando obtienes tu respuesta:

```
res => {
     this.spinner.hide()
     console.log('exito proceso: ',modelRespuesta);
     this.toastr.success("Proceso Ejecutado Exitosamente: ");
                   
},
```

Esto hara que el spinner se oculte cuando el servidor termine de hacer lo necesario y responda, asi la peticion dure 50s el spinner se ocultara hasta que el servidor termine de hacer lo que tenga que hacer y responda.

Comment: y cuando haya error también sino va a quedar dando vueltas

Comment: ¡Exacto! Habria que ocultarlo en ambas **respuestas**, yo solo puse el ejemplo de la respuesta **res** pero habría que ocultarlo en **error** recuerda que **error** no deja de ser una respuesta también, creo que debí de ser más específico y poner también el ejemplo en **error**, no creí que fuera necesario. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para esconder el spinner  utiliza `this.spinner.hide()` y este debe de ir en la respuesta positiva y en la respuesta de error. ya que si sucede un error con el API el spinner seguiría presente

```
this.restService.addData(modelRespuesta, "procesos/respuestas").subscribe(
    res => {
       console.log('exito proceso: ',modelRespuesta);
       this.toastr.success("Proceso Ejecutado Exitosamente: ");
       this.spinner.hide();    
    },
    err => {
       this.error = err.error.mensaje;
       this.toastr.error("Error al ejecutar el proceso almacenado: ", 
       this.error);
       this.spinner.hide()
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

lo más recomendable es que ocultes el spinner cuando recibes la respuesta del servicio por ejemplo, en el front o template puede ir este código en el cual se implementa el spinner de material

```
   <div *ngIf="spinner">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner> 
   </div>
```

y en el código del componente, el ts, puedes crear una variable que al iniciar el componente tenga un valor de falso, después de dar click al botón que llama al servicio, modificar el valor por un true y a la hora de obtener una respuesta del servidor (tanto en data, como en err) modificarlo a false.

sí estas usando el de material, recuerda importarlo en tu módulo raíz (appModule.ts)

```
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
```